Dynamically change WooCommerce product single add to cart button text if product is in cart
In WooCommerce, I would like to update the 'add to cart' text when the corresponding product is added to the cart upon pressing the add to cart button.
Also vice versa, so that the 'add to cart' text is changed when the corresponding product is removed from the cart upon pressing the 'remove from cart button'.
The following code requires a page refresh to reflect the status of the product and update the 'add to cart' button text.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'already_in_cart_single_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
function already_in_cart_single_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text, $product ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if( $item['data']->get_id() === $product->get_id() ) {
            return __('Product already in Cart. Add again?', 'woocommerce');
        }
    } 
    return $add_to_cart_text;
}

However, I'd like it to update upon pressing either the add to cart button or the remove from cart button.

Note that your current code work only for simple products. So my answer code will also work for simple products.
To dynamically update the product add to cart text, if the product is in cart and get removed, it requires JavaScript and Ajax.
Try the following:
// Filter product button single add to cart text
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'already_in_cart_single_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
function already_in_cart_single_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text, $product ) {
    if (!$product->is_type('simple')) {
        return $add_to_cart_text;
    }

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if( $item['data']->get_id() === $product->get_id() ) {
            return __('Product already in Cart. Add again?', 'woocommerce');
        }
    } 
    return $add_to_cart_text;
}


// jQuery Ajax: Check dynamically cart items and update add to cart text via Ajax
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'ajax_update_single_add_to_cart_text' );
function ajax_update_single_add_to_cart_text(){
    global $product;

    if (!$product->is_type('simple')) return;
    
    wc_enqueue_js("$(document.body).on( 'added_to_cart removed_from_cart', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '" . admin_url('/admin-ajax.php') . "',
            data: {
                'action': 'check_cart_items',
                'product_id': ".$product->get_id()."
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('[name=add-to-cart]').html(response)
            }
        });
    });");
}

// PHP AJAX Receiver: Process the ajax request (check cart items)
add_action('wp_ajax_check_cart_items', 'check_cart_items_for_single_add_to_cart_text');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_cart_items', 'check_cart_items_for_single_add_to_cart_text');
function check_cart_items_for_single_add_to_cart_text() {
    if ( isset($_POST['product_id']) && $_POST['product_id'] > 0 ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
            if( $item['data']->get_id() == intval($_POST['product_id']) ) {
                wp_die( __('Product already in Cart. Add again?', 'woocommerce') );
            }
        } 
        wp_die( __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce') );
    }
    wp_die();
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Thank you once again for your help! Massively appreciated. I've decided to go with a 'side cart' option, would it be possible to modify this code to work with a side cart? (current code does not work with side cart). Here is an example of dynamically updating the button upon adding, and removing via the side cart on the product page: https://teletoneaudio.com/products/electro . Of course I can start a new question for this. Thank you!

@Rv5 Single add to cart button text has nothing to do with a side cart... Please ask a new detailed question explaining things, with a real code attempt...
